# php mysql issue with check if record exist before insert

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a little problem with the codes given below. When I'm using the `name="staff_number[]"` then it insert the record with everything ok even if it is already in the database table and when i use `name="staff_number"` it does check the record and also give me alert box but when insert the record if it is not in the database it stores only the first number of the staff number like the staff no is 12345 it stores only 1. can anyone help in this record i think there is only a minor issue what I'm not able to sort out.

**PHP Code:**

```
<select placeholder='Select' style="width:912px;" name="staff_number[]" multiple />
<?php 
$query="SELECT * FROM staff";
$resulti=mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['staff_no']?>"><?php echo $row['staff_name']?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

**Mysql Code:**

```
$prtCheck = $_POST['staff_number'];
$resultsa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff where staff_no ='$prtCheck' ");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($resultsa);
if ($num_rows > 0) {
echo "<script>alert('Staff No $prtCheck Has Already Been Declared As CDP');</script>";
$msg=urlencode("Selected Staff ".$_POST['st_nona']." Already Been Declared As CDP");
echo'<script>location.href = "cdp_staff.php?msg='.$msg.'";</script>';
}
```

**Insert Query**

```
$st_nonas    =  $_POST['st_nona'];
$t_result    = $_POST['st_date'];
$p_result    = $_POST['remarks'];
$arrayResult = explode(',', $t_result[0]);
$prrayResult = explode(',', $p_result[0]);     $arrayStnona = $st_nonas;
$countStnona = count($arrayStnona);


for ($i = 0; $i < $countStnona; $i++) {
    $_stnona  = $arrayStnona[$i];
    $_result  = $arrayResult[$i];
    $_presult  = $prrayResult[$i];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO staff(st_no,date,remarks) 
        VALUES ('".$_stnona."', '".$_result."', '".$_presult."')");
    $msg=urlencode("CDP Staff Has Been Added Successfully");
    echo'<script>location.href = "cdp_staff.php?msg='.$msg.'";</script>';
 }
```

Comment: Can you make your question much more clear .

Comment: I don't see any insert parts ...

Comment: @amit what you want me to clear ??? i am facing problem that when i use array for the staff_number[] the query to verify if record exist or not doesnt work. but when i use staff_number query works fine but when i press Add button it saves only the first number of the Staff Number...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$_POST['staff_number']` is actually an `array`.

So you have to access it like `$_POST['staff_number'][0]` here, `0` is a index number.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. plz tell me one thing only when insert query runs it is not inserting the records which are not in the database

Answer (score 1):

If the name of select is staff_number[] then $prtCheck will be a array so your check query must be in a loop to make sure your check condition.

if the name is staff_number then the below code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of amit is right but I will complete it.

Your HTML form give to your PHP an array due to the use of staff_number[] with [] that it seems legit with the "multiple" attribute.
So you have to loop on the given values, you do it with a for and a lot of useless variables without really checking it. From a long time, we have the FOREACH loop structure.

I could help you more if i know what is the 'st_nona', st_date' and 'remarks' values.

Comment: st_date is multiple date selection box and st_nona is staff no of the selected user

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you are getting difficulty in storing the data. This question is related to $_POST array.

Like your question we have selected following ids from the select : 1,2,3,4
It is only storing 1.
This is due to you have not used the loop when inserting the data.
Like below:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['staffnumber'] as $staffnumber){
$query=mysql_query("select * from staff where staff_number =".$staffnumber);
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
//action you want to perform
}else{
//action you want to perform like entering records etc. as your wish
}
}
?>
```

And I would like to suggest you that use the unique keys in database for field and use PHP PDO for database, as it is secure and best for OOPs.
Let me know if you have any queries.